# How to Transfer Value From One Form Field to Another Field in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

The code below is used to show all plans. As you can see there is a SELECT plan option. I want for any plan when I click on SELECT it should pass its ID to the second field.

I used `$request->gate->id` but it did not work in my Blade file.

```php
@foreach($pack as $gate)
    <div>
        <p style="color: #000">Amount: {{$gate->min_amount}}  {{$general->symbol}} -
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">SELECT</button>
    </div>
@endforeach
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="text" name="package_id" value="{{$gate->id}}"> // I want to Transfer here when click on select.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some jQuery code to set the `gate id` as the value of the input field with the name `package_id`

Try this:

```
@foreach($pack as $gate)
    <div>
        <p style="color: #000">Amount: {{$gate->min_amount}}  {{$general->symbol}} 
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-gate-id="{{$gate->id}}">SELECT</button>
    </div>
@endforeach
<input type="text" name="package_id" value="">
```

Use this jQuery code on the same page:

```
$('.btn-block').on('click', function() {
     var gate_id = $(this).data('gate-id'); // get gate id from button custom attribute data-gate-id on click
     $("input[name='package_id']").val(gate_id); // set gate id in input field
});
```